# Using script variables in html body

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call the variable from the script to body. 
Here is my script code. I want to take the `rightanswers` and `wronganswers` values to use in html body.

```
GetFeedback = function (a) {
    if (a == CorrectAnswer) {
        rightanswers++;
    } else {
        wronganswers++;
    }
    lock = true;
}
```

Comment: where is the HTML ? In what kind of elements do you want the values ?

Comment: I can't define the variables because I am a newbie and trying to find its way:( They can be defined as string.

Comment: First you probably want to actually close the function and I'm supposing declare `GetFeedback` (which should be `getFeedback` as it's not a constructor) with `var`.  (And I'm going to just assume all of the other variables are declared).  It sounds like you're looking for some form of HTML interpolation which doesn't exist.  The closes would be `document.write` calls which are ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Document Object Modle`. You have different methods with JavaScript to create and insert elements into the DOM. As for example:

```
var element = document.createElement('p');
var body = document.body;
body.appendChild(element);
```

With that code you are creating an element, then appendig it into the body. And that is pure JavaScript. You could use `Mootools` or `jQuery`, and It is goign to be simpler. But JavaScript doesn't work like PHP for example, where you can use the variables mixed up with the HTML.

And if you want to trigger the function from the HTML you need to bind thtat function to an event. For example clicking on a link would be.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="button"> Click Here </a>
```

JS

```
var b = document.getElementById('button');
b.click = function(){
   GetFeedback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to change the html on the page.

```
GetFeedback = function(a){
    if(a==CorrectAnswer){
        rightanswers++;
    }else{
        wronganswers++;
    }
    lock=true;
    $('p:first').html('Right Answers: '+rightanswers+' <br> Wrong Answers: '+wronganswers);
};
```

and have this as your html

```
<body>
<p></p>
<a href="javascript:GetFeedback(a);">Get Feedback</a>
</body>
```

Comment: after $('p:first').html('Right Answers: '+rightanswers+' <br> Wrong Answers: '+wronganswers); what do I need to write in body? such as var rightans = ...

Comment: see my update - the `$('p:first')` line will output your script variables into the first paragraph tag on the page. you will need to use the jQuery library to make this work (but then jQuery makes writing javascript much easier - Id highly recommend it even for beginners).

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you're declaring the variable (we can't see that in the code provided) by using `var`**:

```
<script>
    var GetFeedback = function (a) {
        if (a == CorrectAnswer) {
            rightanswers++;

        } else {
            wronganswers++;
        }
        lock = true;
</script>
```

Then in your HTML, you can use feedback like this (**although, it's not good practice to use the below, it's merely for demonstration purposes**):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:GetFeedback();">Hello</a>
```